# Creating application interrupts in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, emulation, interrupt

I am writing a 6502 emulator. I need to simulate interrupts. I will have an I/O chip simulated, that polls the keyboard, and interrupts the simulated cpu to send the keystroke.

I am running on Windows, and know the Windows event handler can do this, but I want to do this in an non OS dependent way.

My gut says this can't be done without OS specific help. Does this just come down to polling in my main loop? I'm simulating a 1 MHz cpu on a 3 GHz computer, so I imagine polling is fine, but I still wonder about real asynchronous  interrupts.

Comment: The occurence of an interrupt is asynchronous by nature; it is generated by external hardware/code. You'll need to add some level of concurrency to your program. I hate C++20 coroutines, but you may give task coroutines a go. However the level of reqired boiler-plate complexity is a turn-off for C++ coroutines(Why I hate them). You can also create an evet loop in a `std::thread` and/or mix some `boost.asio`. The alternative would be spatter interupt hanling code all over your interpreter; pause amidst/after every instruction to check for interupt and continue.

Comment: I think you need to ask a more specific question and decide if you are asking about C or C++. Either way, I do not think you can do proper detection of keystrokes in a platform-independent way.

Comment: You can have a background thread simulating interrupts. But timing on a non realtime os  might be somewhat off.  So you could do an experiment with std::thread, which is platform independent, even if the exact timing you would get might not (but this would be true for polling too). Have a look at std::condition_variable's timed wait too (with predicate!)

Answer (score 2):

At some level you do have to poll, because, like pretty much every CPU in existence, the 6502 doesn't actually invoke the interrupt handler completely asynchronously; only between instructions.  So at the appropriate point in your instruction cycle, you will need a check to see whether the VM should receive an interrupt.

One option is that you poll by calling the OS each time, to check for input.  But the overhead of that is probably excessive.  Even if your emulated CPU is only 1 MHz and takes 5-10 clocks per instruction, you don't want to be making 200,000 system calls per second.

Another is to arrange for the emulator to receive the input asynchronously, in an asynchronous I/O handler or a separate thread, which then sets an atomic flag which the emulation code can test at each cycle.  But watch out for data races and possible deadlocks.

Standard C and C++ have no facilities for processing keystrokes in real time; their I/O model is stream-based.  So yes, this is inherently OS-dependent, unless you use a third-party library that presents a common API for multiple OS-specific back ends.